# c++ classes and defining functions in them?

Tags: c++, c++11, methods

So for my beginning C++ programming class we are writing a program that creates a class for fractions then performing arithmetic on the objects created. The assignment gives a definition for the class `Fraction`, and here are the public members which I'm having the most trouble with understanding. The objects created are `f1`, `f2`, and `fresult`.

```
public:
void inputFrac();
void printFrac();
Fraction fracMult(Fraction b);
Fraction fracDiv(Fraction b);
Fraction fracAdd(Fraction b);
Fraction fracSub(Fraction b);
```

I get that by creating a class you are creating a type, but when I make a call in the main for the `fracMult` function exactly like was also in the template provided to us for the program-->

```
fresult = f1.fracMult(f2);
```

and my function outside of main looks like this

```
Fraction :: Fraction fracMult(Fraction b)
{
Fraction x;
x.numerator = fraction.numerator * b.numerator;
x.denom = fraction.denom * b.denom;
if (fraction.positive == true && b.positive == false ||
        fraction.positive == false && b.positive == true)
{
    x.positive = false;
}
else (fraction.positive == true && b.positive == true ||
        fraction.positive == false && b.positive == false)
{
    x.positive = true;
}
return (x);
}
```

I get an error

> main.cpp:79:1: error: 'Fraction::Fraction' names the constructor, not the type
>   Fraction :: Fraction fracMult(Fraction b)

I'm just really confused in general about how the type for the functions in the class can be the name of the class, and how I'm supposed to then format the function outside of main.

Comment: :: is used to specify where something is. The function `fracMult` is inside `Fraction`. Right now, you have a global `fracMult` function returning a `Fraction` inside of `Fraction`, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

To implement a member function, your must reference it as `ClassName::functionName`. Here the first `Fraction` isn't a reference to the class' name, but the function's return value, which just happens to be of the same type.

In short, it should be written as follows:

```
Fraction Fraction::fracMult(Fraction b) {
    // implementation here
}
```

Comment: Oh jeez, I can't believe I missed that. Too many Fraction 's floating around (unfortunately). Got it working now, thanks!